# Embed Several info fields in a XML Node Content

Tags: xml, serialization, embedding

I have two XML Documents, on the first I have:

```
<IamAXMLNode attr1="50%" attr2="Cool" attr3="I am a free text optional cool attribute" />
```

But in the second one, the whole info of IamAXMLNode attributes should be included on a single attribute:

```
<ACollageNode type="IamAXMLNode">'content of the three attr unified'</ACollageNode>
```

ACollageNode content must match on a grammar as alphanumeric string

It is not possible to change the schema of the XML Documents.

The options I am handling are:

- Included them as text using a separator (I will find a separator that is not used on any field). What if the day after tomorrow specs change and the character could be used on those attributes? :S
- Serialize to byte array and use a safe separator. Is there any tool to do this? some Boost library like Serialize would be useful?
- Using CDATA. Actually, I would like to encode the info, not the whole XML Node

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to add the xml document as a CDATA node under ACollageNode instead of an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally add a separator and scape the occurrences on the fields... since the output had to be human readable.